# Can't delete, do anything to important question

Tags: support, closed-questions

A question of mine got auto-migrated here, but now it is locked and I can't edit or do anything with it.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/42496/magento-community-1-4-separate-admin-server

Either delete it permanently or let me edit it, as this is a critical issue for us and the Magento forums are down.

Thanks.

Comment: If this is going to be a pattern (SE migrates magento Q, MageExchange 'locks' question and is uneditable) I'm definitely not going to recommend this site.

Comment: Hm, it's strange that you can't edit it. Can you please post a screenshot?

Comment: thats the result of the migration, we cant even reopen it here :(
Could you please repost your question(and directly change the topic to "what to consider in case of different server for frontend and admin")

Answer (score 2):

as already mentioned in the comment, please ask this question new here, because we are not able to reopen the question here.

Also some hints to your Problem in the question.

there is a lot to consider.

- Have the same database
- media needs to be shared between bot servers, or using an external file storage like from amazon
- you cant install modules from connect anymore, or at least it needs a complex code sharing process, which you dont want. You should install modules by hand now, or on dev machines and commit them to your vcs.
- Depending on the modules you use other issues can happen too
- depending on your cache backend, it can happen that a cache clean on admin server, does not clean any caches on the frontend server